# How to dynamically add panels to TCategoryPanelGroup?

Tags: delphi

How to dynamically I can add panels to an TCategoryPanelGroup.

Give me a example please, thanks.

This i tried so far.

```
procedure TWForm.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  categorypanel: tcategorypanel;
begin
  categorypanel := categorypanel.Create (categorypanelgroup1);
  categorypanel := tcategorypanel.Create(self);
  categorypanel.caption:=edit1.text;
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must create the component and then set the `PanelGroup` property of the [CategoryPanel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanel) with the CategoryPanelGroup.

```
Var
 LPanel : TCategoryPanel;
begin
 LPanel:=TCategoryPanel.Create(CategoryPanelGroup1);
 LPanel.Caption:='My Panel';
 LPanel.PanelGroup:=CategoryPanelGroup1;
end;
```